# How to implement fast search on Azure Blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am done with writing the code to upload files (text files) to azure blob storage. Now I want to provide search based on text files content. For ex. If I search for "Hello" then the name of files that contains "Hello" words should appear in search result. Here my code to search

```
class BlobSearch
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string searchText = "Hello";
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureConString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("MyBlobContainer");

        blobContainer.FetchAttributes();

        var blobItemList = blobContainer.ListBlobs();

        foreach (var item in blobItemList)
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Uri.ToString());

            if(blockBlob.Name.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                int lineno = 1;                    
                using (var stream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (line.IndexOf(searchText) != -1)
                            {                                    
                                Console.WriteLine("Line : " + lineno  +" => "+ blockBlob.Name);
                            }
                            lineno++;
                        }
                    }
                }                  
            }                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SEARCH COMPLETE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Above code is working but it is too slow. Is there any way to do it faster or Can improve above code.

Comment: are you looking for any special keywords (a limited set) that you can add an additional column and set when you are first inserting the blob (basically attributes) and then you can search on the attributes rather than against the blob field.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
No, I want to search file based on the content of text file.

Comment: The most obvious alternative to what @KevinCook said, is to build your own full text index, a list of words linked to the files they appear in. This is more powerful, but obviously a lot more work.

Comment: how big are the files? can they be stored in a varchar(max) and then you can search using sql on the db rather than pulling the file down across the network?

Comment: I agree with @KevinCook on using SQL Server full text indexing, but then of course there is no point (nor need) to use blob storage.

Comment: @Kevin Cook
Yes, it can be stored in varcha(max) but how can i use sql again blob storage?

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten
You are right..

Comment: is there a reason you have to use blob storage? is this homework?

Comment: @Kevin
No reason, but it is requirement.

Comment: @KevinCook Probably because blob storage is significantly cheaper than a SQL database on Azure.

Comment: private async static void Search(string searchText, CloudBlockBlob blockBlob)
{
     string text = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
     if (text.IndexOf(searchText) != -1)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(blockBlob.Name);
     }
}

It makes much faster than previous.

Comment: Why re-invent? How about using lucene for azure http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538

Answer (score 1):

```
// get blob data
CloudBlob cloudBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);
string text = cloudBlob.DownloadText();
```

Maybe downloading it in one go is faster than reading line by line in a loop?

Comment: Thanks kevin it helps. Now better than previous.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very bad way to do it. It will be very slow. The best option for this is [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-what-is-azure-search/). Search can now automatically index your blobs!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not bad. Find out where most time is spent. Probably network or CPU. For network, you are out of luck. For CPU you can parallelize.

You are using culture-specific string processing. `StringComparison.Ordinal` is far less CPU intensive (like 10x). It has different semantics, though.